# `missing tag key` when inserting to InfluxDB with inserting with multiple tags

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python, influxql, chronograf, influxdb-2

I created a new db `mydb` on Influxdb.
Next I did `use mydb`
When I run insert on my db, I run into error - 
`ERR: {"error":"unable to parse 'angle, userid=1, product=pname value=5.1': missing tag key"}`

Here's the insert that I am running - 
`INSERT angle, userid=1, product=dname value=5.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking docs and multiple hit and tries I figured outthe correct way to insert in influxDb with multiple tags is this -

`INSERT angle,id=1,product=ineck value=5.0`

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/syntax/line-protocol/

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `angle` is the name of the measurement and `userid`, `product` and `value` are fields, try removing the comma after `angle` if you are not applying any tags and add another comma before `value` ?

```
INSERT angle userid=1,product=dname,value=5.1
```

If `userid` is a tag then it should be something like

```
INSERT angle,userid=1 product=dname,value=5.1
```

Please refer to line protocol specification
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/write_protocols/line_protocol_tutorial/

Comment: `userid` is a tag and the second one throws this error -
`ERR: {"error":"unable to parse 'angle,userid=1 product=dname,value=5.1': invalid boolean"}`

Answer (score 3):

Currently learning influxdb and my issue was the spaces. Make sure you have the correct spaces.

Your insert command:

```
INSERT angle, userid=1, product=dname value=5.1
```

Properly formatted with spaces corrected:

```
INSERT angle,userid=1,product=dname value=5.1
```

I would have left a comment beneath the answer but I don't have the reputation for it and no one explicitly mentioned the issue with the spaces.
So for any newcomers, pay attention to your spaces.